Canonical transformation in which $P=H(p,q)$
Can you give me an example of a canonical transformation satisfying $P=H(p,q)$? The problem reduces to solving the equation
$$1=[Q,P]_{q,p}=\dot q \frac{\partial Q}{\partial q}+\dot p \frac{\partial Q}{\partial p}.\tag{1}$$
An attempted solution I found on a book claims that
$$Q=t-t_0\tag{2}$$
is one such example but I am quite sure it's wrong since it doesn't satisfy the Poisson bracket invariance condition. So am I missing something or is the example flawed? Moreover, can somebody find a suitable example?

Which book? Which page?

It is an exercise taken from "Paolo Rossi: Meccanica classica". It's an Italian textobook for classical mechanics


Presumably the Hamiltonian $H(q,p)$ is assumed to have no explicit time dependence, and hence is equal to the Kamiltonian $K$ and a COM, whose constant value we identify with the first integration constant $\alpha_1$.

We now assume that Hamilton's characteristic function $W(q,P)$ [which is a generating function for a canonical transformation (CT) of type 2] exists. Here the new momenta $P_j$ are identified with the integration constants $\alpha_j$, where $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

From Kamilton's equations $$\dot{Q}^j~\approx~\frac{\partial K}{\partial P_j}~=~\frac{\partial P_1}{\partial P_j}~=~\delta^j_1,$$ we see that
the new positions are COM$^\dagger$
$$ Q^j~\approx~\delta^j_1 t + \beta^j,$$
except for the the first position $Q^1$, which plays the role of time $t$.


References:

H. Goldstein, Classical Mechanics, 2nd ed; eq. (10-28b).

H. Goldstein, Classical Mechanics, 3rd ed; eq. (10.46).



$^\dagger$ Here the $\approx$ symbol denotes equality modulo EOMs.

Okay but why does it (apparently) not satisfy the invariance of Poisson brackets? I mean if you expand the calculation $[Q,P]$ you get zero for every Q term because it doesn't depend on q,p. What am I missing?

Poisson brackets (1) do not necessarily hold for solutions (2).

But then it wouldn't be canonical yet you assumed that there exists a generating function W for the transformation and a new Hamiltonian K from which you derived the equations for Q. Why can Poisson brackets not hold in this case?

Maybe I got it, confirm if I am right: 1. a canonical transformation is such that for every Hamiltonian H you can find a new Hamiltonian K for which canonical equations hold. 2. In our case we have only one such Hamiltonian that satisfies our condition and for which we can find K that gives us Q in the end. 3. Yet it is not necessarily true that Poisson bracket invariance hold because it is not a canonical trasformation after all according to the definition

Point 3 is not really the issue as different definitions of CT typically agree.
